# acceleoCompiler not showing output in console output with ant

Tags: eclipse, ant, eclipse-emf, acceleo

I am using `acceleoCompiler` inside an ant script and when i run the ant script everything shows an output except acceleoCompiler.

For instance, `[javac]` and `[mkdir]` shows up. But nothing relating to `acceleoCompiler` shows up. Am i doing something wrong?

The ant script:

```
<eclipse.refreshLocal resource="${F_FOLDER}/bin/" depth="infinite"/>
<eclipse.refreshLocal resource="${FE_FOLDER}/bin/" depth="infinite"/>

<mkdir dir="${F_OUTPUT}"/>
<mkdir dir="${FE_OUTPUT}"/>

<javac 
    srcdir="${F_SRC}generator/" 
    destdir="${FR_OUTPUT}"
        executable="${JAVA_JDK}/javac"
        fork="true"
        includeantruntime="false"
        failonerror="false"
/>
    <javac 
        srcdir="${FE_SRC}generator/" 
        destdir="${FE_OUTPUT}"
        executable="${JAVA_JDK}/javac"
        fork="true"
        includeantruntime="false"
        failonerror="false"
    />

<acceleoCompiler sourceFolder="${F_SRC}"
        outputFolder="${F_OUTPUT}"
        dependencies=""
        binaryResource="true"
        packagesToRegister="org.eclipse.emf.ecore.EcorePackage">
</acceleoCompiler>


<acceleoCompiler sourceFolder="${F_SRC}" 
    outputFolder="${FE_OUTPUT}" 
    dependencies="" 
    binaryResource="true" 
    packagesToRegister="org.eclipse.emf.ecore.EcorePackage">
</acceleoCompiler>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The absence of logging messages doesn't mean you're doing anything wrong.  If you look at the source for `mkdir` or `javac` you'll see that they call the Ant Task method `log()` in most cases.  The Acceleo Ant task however only calls `log()` if it finds a problem - if all is well it is silent and enigmatic.

References:

- Ant [mkdir task source](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/ant/ant-1.8.0/org/apache/tools/ant/taskdefs/Mkdir.java.html).
- [AcceleoCompiler source](http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/index.cgi/org.eclipse.m2t/org.eclipse.acceleo/plugins/org.eclipse.acceleo.parser/src-ant/org/eclipse/acceleo/parser/compiler/AcceleoCompiler.java?revision=1.13&root=Modeling_Project&view=markup) via the *[Acceleo wiki FAQ](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Acceleo/FAQ#How_can_I_compile_my_mtl_files_in_a_standalone_environment.3F).*

Comment: Thank you, makes me feel a little better. =)